# Convert inline specified UTF-8 mail subject

Tags: php, email, encoding, utf-8

want to convert the following raw mail subject to normal UTF-8 text:

> =?utf-8?Q?Schuker_hat_sich_vom_=C3=9Cbungsabend_(01.01.2012)_abgem?=  =?utf-8?Q?eldet?=

The real text for that is:

> Schuker hat sich vom Übungsabend (01.01.2012) abgemeldet

My first approach to convert this:

```
$mime = '=?utf-8?Q?Schuker_hat_sich_vom_=C3=9Cbungsabend_(01.01.2012)_abgem?=  =?utf-8?Q?eldet?=';
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
echo mb_decode_mimeheader($mime);
```

This gives me the following result:

> Schuker_hat_sich_vom_Übungsabend_(01.01.2012)_abgemeldet

(Questions here: What am I doing wrong? Why do those underscores occur?)

My second approach to convert this:

```
$mime = '=?utf-8?Q?Schuker_hat_sich_vom_=C3=9Cbungsabend_(01.01.2012)_abgem?=  =?utf-8?Q?eldet?=';
echo imap_utf8($mime);
```

This gives me the following (correct) result:

> Schuker hat sich vom Übungsabend (01.01.2012) abgemeldet

Why does this work? On which method should I rely on?

The reason I ask is that I previously asked another [mail subject decoding related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193854/convert-inline-specified-utf-8-mail-subject-to-utf-8-text) where `mb_decode_mimeheader` was the solution whereas here `imap_utf8` would be the way to go. How can I ensure to decode everything correct for those both examples:

> =?utf-8?Q?Schuker_hat_sich_vom_=C3=9Cbungsabend_(01.01.2012)_abgem?=  =?utf-8?Q?eldet?

and

> =?UTF-8?B?UmU6ICMyLUZpbmFsIEFjY2VwdGFuY2UgdGVzdCB3aXRoIG5ldyB0ZXh0IHdpdGggU2xvdg==?=
>           =?UTF-8?B?YWsgaW50ZXJwdW5jdGlvbnMgIivEvsWhxI3FpcW+w73DocOtw6khxYgi?=

Should give me the expected results:

> Schuker hat sich vom Übungsabend (01.01.2012) abgemeldet

and

> Re: #2-Final Acceptance test with new text with Slovak interpunctions "+ľščťžýáíé!ň"

Comment: Are you sure that real text contain spaces? It looks like it was encoded with underscores or application that encoded it is buggy. There is no need to encode spaces and even if it gets encoded, it should be `=20` not underscore.

Comment: Yes, the real text contains spaces. Please see the revised question. Thanks!

Comment: That is how RFC 2048 modifies quoted-printable for use in 7-bit headers. The =?encoding?x?...?= wrapper is also defined in that spec. - If `imap_utf8` gives you the correct result, I wouldn't hesitate to use that (but then, I'd hesitate to use PHP in the first place, so I might not be a legit source :-) Does `mb_decode_mimeheaders` work correctly if you stick `"Subject: "` in front of your test string?

Comment: No, adding `Subject` does not help. Only using `imap_utf8` is not helping as it fails to convert the second subject line `Re: #2...`

Comment: I presume `imap_utf8()` is adding a BOM (byte order mark) at the beginning, so the strings are not equal (invisible characters)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the [hbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501810/hbit) response, I've improved the `imapUtf8()` function to convert the subject text to UTF-8 using the charset information. The result is something like:

```
function imapUtf8($str){
    $convStr = '';
    $subLines = preg_split('/[\r\n]+/', $str);
    for ($i=0; $i < count($subLines); $i++) {
        $convLine = '';
        $linePartArr = imap_mime_header_decode($subLines[$i]);
        for ($j=0; $j < count($linePartArr); $j++) {
            if ($linePartArr[$j]->charset === 'default') {
                if ($linePartArr[$j]->text != " ") {
                    $convLine .= ($linePartArr[$j]->text);
                }
            } else {
                $convLine .= iconv($linePartArr[$j]->charset, 'UTF-8', $linePartArr[$j]->text);
            }
        }
        $convStr .= $convLine;
    }

    return $convStr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's also in the comments in the manual for [`mb_decode_mimeheader`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-decode-mimeheader.php), and I actually assume it is a bug. None in the database, so I'd file it as a new one.

However, AFAIK [`imap_mime_header_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mime-header-decode.php) will cope with both your encodings without a problem, so that will keep your code going.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me the right direction - `imap_mime_header_decode` turned out to solve the issue (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

This function works for both examples:

```
function imapUtf8($str){
    $convStr = '';
    $subLines = preg_split('/[\r\n]+/',$str); // split multi-line subjects
    for($i=0; $i < count($subLines); $i++){ // go through lines
        $convLine = '';
        $linePartArr = imap_mime_header_decode(trim($subLines[$i])); // split and decode by charset
        for($j=0; $j < count($linePartArr); $j++){
            $convLine .= ($linePartArr[$j]->text); // append sub-parts of line together
        }
        $convStr .= $convLine; // append to whole subject
    }
    return $convStr; // return converted subject
}
```

Tests:

```
$sub1 = '=?utf-8?Q?Schuker_hat_sich_vom_=C3=9Cbungsabend_(01.01.2012)_abgem?=  =?utf-8?Q?eldet?=';
$sub2 = '=?UTF-8?B?UmU6ICMyLUZpbmFsIEFjY2VwdGFuY2UgdGVzdCB3aXRoIG5ldyB0ZXh0IHdpdGggU2xvdg==?= =?UTF-8?B?YWsgaW50ZXJwdW5jdGlvbnMgIivEvsWhxI3FpcW+w73DocOtw6khxYgi?=';
echo imapUtf8($sub1);
echo imapUtf8($sub2);
```

Result:

> Schuker hat sich vom Übungsabend (01.01.2012) abgemeldet
>
> Re: #2-Final Acceptance test with new text with Slovak interpunctions "+ľščťžýáíé!ň"

Comment: You should also check the $linePartArr[$j]->charset before appending each sub-part (and convert the string to UTF-8, when necessary).

Comment: `preg_split()` should use the /u modifier

Answer (score 1):

About the mysterious underscore in the Subject header field:

[RFC2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) 4.2(2) states explicitly:

> The 8-bit hexadecimal value 20 (e.g., ISO-8859-1 SPACE) may be
> represented as "_" (underscore, ASCII 95.).  (This character may
> not pass through some internetwork mail gateways, but its use
> will greatly enhance readability of "Q" encoded data with mail
> readers that do not support this encoding.)  Note that the "_"
> **always represents** hexadecimal 20, even if the SPACE character
> occupies a different code position in the character set in use.

The encoding rule for Subject line is documented in the very RFC2047 .